# pipe character "|" was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have the following script to find a class in a number of JARs. Class name is passed as a string argument.

```
set ARG=%1
for /R %G in (*.jar) do @jar -tvf %G | find %ARG% > NUL && echo %G
```

Gives me the following error

```
> findClassInJar.bat "ContentPartition"
> set ARG="ContentPartition"
| was unexpected at this time.
> for /R G | find "ContentPartition" > NUL && echo G
```

How can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `%%` instead of `%` for the loop variable in batch files. That is, replace `%G` with `%%G`. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as an argument.

Comment: Thanks. Did the change. Now apparently its searching for the string without Quotes - gives me a file not found exception

Comment: @Jay Replace `%ARG%` with `"%ARG%"`.

Comment: set ARG=%1
for /R %%G in (*.jar) do @jar -tvf %%G | find %ARG% > NUL && echo %%G - This works